# Python handle input().split with default case

Tags: python, exception, input

How to handle input().split() if I enter only 1 parameter?

```
surname = "Smith";

# if I enter name and surname => print name and surname
# if I enter only name print name and "Smith" as surname

name, surname = input("\n Enter name ").split()
print("name :",name)
print("surname:",surname)
```

Think I have to try except...?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Python 3 you can use [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) (just keep in mind that `surname` will be a list):

```
name, *surname = input("\n Enter name ").split()
if not surname:
    surname = ['Smith']
print("name :",name)
print("surname:", ' '.join(surname))
```

Examples

```
Enter name a
name : a
surname: Smith

Enter name a b c
name : a
surname: b c

Enter name a bc
name : a
surname: bc
```

`try-except` could be used for a more explicit solution:

```
split_name = input("\n Enter name ").split(' ', maxsplit=1)
try:
    name, surname = split_name
except ValueError:
    name, surname = split_name[0], 'Smith'
print("name :", name)
print("surname:", surname)
```

Output is the same as before

```
Enter name a
name : a
surname: Smith

Enter name a bc
name : a
surname: bc

Enter name a b c
name : a
surname: b c
```

Comment: oh now this is one thing i would never have thought of, i was thinking along the lines of read it all into a single list then check if list is longer than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Including case of three words.

```
sent = input("\n Enter name ").split()

if len(sent) == 1:
    name, surname = sent[0], '-'
else:
    name = sent[0]
    sent.remove(sent[0])
    surname = ' '.join(sent)
print(name, " ", surname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 surname = 'Smith'
 data = raw_input("\n Enter name ").split()

 if len(data) == 1:
     name, surname = data[0],surname 
 else:
     name = data[0]
     data.remove(data[0])
     surname = ''.join(data)
 print("name :",name)
 print("surname:",surname)
```